# How to find all points with certain elevation difference between them in QGIS

Tags: point, elevation, spatial-analysis

I have a point layer (xyz) and want to find all points that have elevation difference of 200m or more. I would like to then draw a line between each pair with the largest elevation difference.

The goal is to identify areas that have large elevation difference and (eventually) nearest distance between them in QGIS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to import your points into a format that can be queried with SQL, like PostGIS, SQLite or Shapefile (using OGR).

Then you can query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table] a, [table] b 
WHERE a.[featureid] <> b.[featureid] 
    AND ST_Z(a.[geometry]) - ST_Z(b.[geometry]) >= 200;
```

Or you can query and make lines in one step:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(a.[geometry], b.[geometry]) AS geom 
FROM [table] a, [table] b 
WHERE a.[featureid] <> b.[featureid] 
    AND ST_Z(a.[geometry]) - ST_Z(b.[geometry]) >= 200;
```

It might help to filter out any points that cannot be >= 200m from another point first, because this is an O(n^2) query -- if you have a lot of points, it'll take a long time. You can also restrict the matching to within a certain distance to employ the index and speed it up.

Note: replace the [names] here with your own table/column names.

*Edit:*

I couldn't find where to execute an SQL query in QGIS, but here's how to do it in [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) on the command line:

```
ogr2ogr \
    -f "ESRI Shapefile" \
    -dialect "SQLITE" \
    -sql "SELECT * FROM input a, input b WHERE ST_Z(a.GEOMETRY)-ST_Z(b.GEOMETRY) < 200 AND a.FID<>b.FID" \
    output.shp input.shp
```

The -f switch tells the program what kind of file to produce. The -dialect switch says to use SQLite's SQL engine to perform the query. The -sql argument is the query. GEOMETRY and FID are built-in field names that you can use in your query.

Now, this query is going to be extremely slow because there's no index. It's going to try to match every point to every other point. Using the documentation [here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=SpatialIndex) I tried to get the query to use a spatial index, but it doesn't seem to work and I don't have time to mess with it at the moment.

Loading the same point set into SpatiaLite goes something like this:

```
spatialite> .loadshp input input UTF-8 2956
spatialite> select createspatialindex('input', 'geometry');
spatialite> create table output as select * from input a, input b where st_z(a.geometry)-st_z(b.geometry) < 200 and a.rowid<>b.rowid and a.rowid in (select rowid from spatialindex f_table_name='stations' and search_frame=b.geometry);
spatialite> .dumpshp output 'geometry' output UTF-8
```

The first line loads the shp file, the second creates a spatial index, the third creates a new table from the query and the fourth dumps the new table to a new file. ([Docs here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/impexp.html).)

This is much faster than the ogr2ogr solution (for me).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please bare with me and my beginner questions:

Comment: I converted the point layer to a shapefile, are you suggesting to query it in QGIS' "select by expression" function or query it in some other SQL capable program? Or is there a SQL plugin I need for QGIS? Right now, all elevation points are in one table - are you suggesting  to duplicate them into table a and table b? Also, for points, what [geometry] should I use?

Comment: to clarify: my point file has the following fields: field_1 (this is feature ID), field_2 (this is x coordinate of each point), field_3 (y coordinate) and filed_4 (z coordinate of each point).

Comment: If your data were in postgis or spatialite, the right place to query it would be in  databases > db manager.

Comment: @Rob. Thank you for your suggestions. Can you please walk me through the concept of input a , input b? Are you suggesting I have two tables (a and b) in the input shape file? should I just duplicate the original point table?

Comment: Actually, you don't duplicate anything. That just tells the SQL interpeter that you're doing a cross join, so you're comparing input to itself. (This syntax is actually functionally equivalent to `input a CROSS JOIN input b`.) The `a` and `b` are just aliases so you can refer to the sides of the join unambiguously.

Comment: To clarify further, that syntax `input a` is a bit confusing. It's not "here's an input called 'a'", it's "here's an input called 'input' with the alias 'a'". You could also write `input AS a`, which would be clearer.

Comment: Great, got that. Thank you @Rob. I managed to create the spatial index, but am getting error: "no such function: st_z" am I missing some configuration file or something? I had to download init_spatialite-2.3.sql separately from my spatialite, so wondering if I missed something else.

Comment: Are you working with ogr2ogr or spatialite? If it's the former, ogr has to be compiled with spatialite to use the sqlite dialect. If it's the latter, are you getting the `spatialite>` prompt? (Start spatialite by running `spatialite` not `sqlite`.)

Comment: I'm using spatialite, and I get the spatialite> prompt. (started spatialite not sqlite). But I just noticed that x(geom) and y(geom) return a value (the x and y coordinate of a point), but z(geom) doesn't. Did I not load the shape file correctly? The z values are in the table under field_4. I will try to re-write the query with filed_4 to get the z value.... let's see if that works.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was assuming that elevations were stored in a 3D geometry. If they're in fields just subtract them like `a.field_4 - b.field_4`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26727/discussion-between-peterb-and-rob-skelly).